# minimum value from uniform_real_distribution()

Tags: c++, c++11, random

In my program, I generate uniform random numbers between 0 and 1 using `uniform_real_distribution()`

```
#include <random>

default_random_engine e;
uniform_real_distribution<double> u(0,1);

double rand_num = u(e);
```

I'm wondering that what is the minimum value of the generated random number except 0. i.e. minimum gap between two random number.

Comment: Presumably `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` (a.k.a. `DBL_MIN`).

Comment: There's also denormalized numbers to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) to answer this question in general.

`std::nextafter(from, to)` returns the next representable floating point value(could be denormal) of `from` in the direction of `to`.

For the case of `from == 0.0`, you could also use `std::numeric_limits<F>::denorm_min()`, where `F` is the floating-point type you care about. While `std::numeric_limits<F>::denorm_min()` always returns the minimum positive representable value, it could be a denormalized number. If `F` does not support denormals, the return value will be equal to `std::numeric_limits<F>::min()`.

Thanks to WhozCraig and T.C. for the correction.

Comment: Interestingly, `std::numeric_limits<double>min()` and `std::nextafter(0.0, 1.0)` report different values on my OS X 10.10.2 rig, 2.22507e-308 and 4.94066e-324 respectively.

Comment: @WhozCraig denormalized numbers, probably. Try `std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()`

Comment: @WhozCraig : What about `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`?

Comment: @ildjarn not nearly as small: `2.22045e-16`.

Comment: @TC yup. that was it. `denorm_min` and `nextafter` report the same (see above for value).

Comment: Looks like both libstdc++ and libc++ [can generate denormalized numbers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/585be0cdece94068), so I'm guessing that the minimum will be `std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()`. The standard doesn't specify anything explicitly for this.